# The specified source 'Artifactory' is invalid. Provide a valid source error for nuget push command

Tags: c#, command-line, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-push

with below command i am getting The specified source 'Artifactory' is invalid. Provide a valid source error while running the command from ADO pipeline command prompt task.

C:\NuGet\nuget.exe push E:\adoagent03_work\1\a.....\Release\Nugetpackage.1.0.0.nupkg -Source Artifactory

in build agent , I have added the source already with command  "nuget sources Add -Name Artifactory -Source https://........./artifactory/api/nuget/v3/Nuget -username  -virtualpassword

and also executed the command "nuget setapikey username:password -Source Artifactory"

i have executed the same push command from command prompt directly in the build agent and it got pushed to artifactory without any issue.

only from ADO pipeline command prompt task getting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ado build agent was setup with NTService account and the nuget.config file is not present with the specific NTservice account.

So i have removed and re created agent with my account, now the push task is working fine.